# Make special query log for a certain zone bind9

Tags: domain-name-system, logging, bind

How do I make special query log file from a certain zone.

While my current log config is

```
logging {
        channel query_logging {
                file "/var/log/named/query.log" versions 5>
                //severity debug 1;
                print-time yes;
                //print-severity yes;
                //print-category yes;
        };

        category queries {
                query_logging;
        };
};
```

That config is logging all queries from any zone and save it to one file. What I want is I want record for specify zone and save the log to specify file.

For example zone `example.com`.

So for any query line that contain example.com word will saved to specify file.

Note: my zone is encapsulated by view.

If bind can't handle it, maybe regex can do it? But how save the regex result to a file periodically? I'm wonder it will be waste CPU resource if use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

But you could forward all logging to SyslogNG or equivalent where you have full regex capability to split a given stream in multiple files or other sinks.

PS: maybe the feature exists in other nameservers, do you have any specific reason to consider only `bind`?

Comment: Because nameserver I only know is ```bind```

Comment: dnsdist may be able to do what you need. I don't find anything in either PowerDNS or nsd.

Comment: Or KnotDNS, considering https://knot-resolver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules-policy.html#mod-policy-logging